# Choosing "shut down" or "power off" causes some programs to close

Tags: gnome3

I'm trying to find out why Lyx (version 2.1.1) closes down as soon as I choose "shut down" in the gnome menu. This does not seem to be a bug in Lyx, as running Lyx with gdb tells me that it has exited normally when I click "shut down".

I don't think it's related to any of the gnome shell extensions I've installed, as disabling all of them (and finding back gnome's "power off" button) doesn't change this weird behaviour.

What happens *always* when choosing "shut down", is that Lyx closes down. *Sometimes*, when I exit from the "shut down" dialog by "cancel", the next time I click on "shut down", nothing happens. So gnome seems affected by this strange behaviour as well, and I have to restart the computer from the terminal.

FYI, the "shut down" dialog allows to suspend the computer; if it allowed only to power off or restart the machine, this would not have been an issue.

Lyx is based on Qt, so the problem might be there as well.
I'm running CentOS 7 with Gnome version 3.8.4.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you actually expecting another behavior? What behavior you expect of applications when you select "shut down"?

Comment: The "shut down" button gives access to the options "suspend", "hibernate", "restart", "power off" and "cancel". Indeed, if I restart the machine or power it off, I'd expect the applications to close ; but when suspending the machine, most applications (terminal, firefox, libreoffice, acroread, ...) stay open, and allow me to resume work where I left it. Only LyX closes, as far as I know, but it's not impossible that other applications are concerned.

Comment: Check : skype also closes when opening the "shut down" dialog. Skype is also qt-based, right? So the error might be there ...

Comment: @Braiam - I think the issue here is that the apps are closing before he's had a chance to pick an option from the "shutdown" dialog.

Comment: Indeed. And in the case I choose "suspend", I don't want the programs to shut down. As it seems to be a Qt-related issue (LyX, skype, vlc ...), I submitted the problem on the Qt forum : https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/47632/

Comment: @Jos - I agree, this sounds like a Qt/KDE related issue. What you're experiencing is not the norm.

Comment: I also annoyingly experience the issue with VLC Player on Arch Linux with GNOME 3.24.2. Any progress on this?